# JPA - don't want to hard code unitName in @PersistenceContext

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I am using eclipselink and I have something like this:

@PersistenceContext(unitName = "unit1")
    private EntityManager em;

Is there any way that I can specify/read the persistent unit name from a config/property file so that if I want, i can change the persistent unit name (so that it will point to a different data source)?

Comment: Do you have more than one persistent unit in your configuration file? If not you can just remove the `unitName`

Comment: Similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5104185/how-to-inject-persistence-context-to-different-data-source-programmatically/5280608#5280608

Answer (score 0):

Don't use injection, lookup the context in code.